Could someone explain this leap in the Feynman lectures that 'derives' the fourth Lorentz transformation equation
So suppose that two coordinate systems are in uniform relative motion. Then the Lorentz transformation is:
$$x' =\frac{x-ut}{\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}}$$
$$y' = y$$
$$z' = z$$
$$t' = \frac{t- ux/c^2}{\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}}$$
Feynman explains the first equation by the reasoning:

Suppose that Moe, moving with the $S'$ system in the $x$-direction, is measuring the $x'$-coordinate of some point with a meter stick. He lays the stick down $x'$ times, so he thinks the distance is $x'$ meters. From the viewpoint of Joe in the $S$ system, however, Moe is using a foreshortened ruler, so the “real” distance measured is $x'\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}$ meters. Then if the $S'$ system has travelled a distance $ut$ away from the $S$ system, the $S$ observer would say that the same point, measured in his coordinates, is at a distance $x=x'\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}+ut$, or
$$x'=\frac{x-ut}{\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}},$$

which is the first equation of the Lorentz transformation.
Now for the fourth equation, the explanation states

"In an analogous way, because of the difference in time scales, the denominator expression is introduced into the fourth equation of the Lorentz transformation."

But I don't understand how the fourth equation is derived.
Edit: So I tried to figure out the derivation and came up with this but I don't know if it is right.
Similar to the derivation of the first equation. Assume that Moe measures $t'$ to be the amount of time light takes to reach $x'$ but since in Joe's frame $x'$ is shortened by a factor of $\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}$ to Joe, Moe's time $=t'\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}$ also from Joe's point of view light has to travel a distance $ut$ further so it takes extra time $\frac{ut}{c}=\frac{ux}{c^2}$ to reach $x$. Therefore $$t = t'\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}+ ux/c^2$$
or $$t' = \frac{t - ux/c^2}{\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}}$$

Feynman gives an explanation of how the Lorentz factor is introduced to the fourth equation in the preceding section: "15–4 Transformation of time". In the following section, "15–6 Simultaneity", he also gives an intuition on where the $ux/c^2$ term comes from in this equation.. did you keep reading?

I understood the Lorentz factor introduction in 15-4. But I didn't understand 15-6.
I understand that if Moe records some interval of time. From Joe's point of view Moe's time is shorter and therefore. Therefore t = $t'\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}$ but I don't understand where the $+ ux/c^2$ term comes from.

So see this very similar question: How to derive the $vx/c^2$ term from first principles?

By analogy with the first approach by replacing the time in $ut$ by $t=x/c$ ("the system S'
moved away a distance ut
of system S"), i.e. $x-ux/c$, and to have the time dimension for the light we divide by c : $t-ux/c^{2}$

@Amit does my derivation in the edit make sense, is it valid?

@MonsterRamen The idea is correct but I think your usage of symbols is a bit confusing: you're using $t$ with two different meanings, it's wrong to write $ut/c = ux/c^2$ , note in particular we can take $t=0$ but $x\neq 0$ which implies this is wrong. It would be correct if you take $\Delta t$ rather than $t$ as some interval of time in which one system is moving relative to the other. Then, it's true that even in synchronizing clocks classically but with a finite speed of light, the extra factor of $ux/c^2$ is necessary (independently of the Lorentz factor).

Here's one way that I think is rather simple to derive the fourth equation for $t'$.
Begin by considering how observers in a frame may synchronize their clocks. One of the simplest ways is to imagine that at time $t=t'=0$, a light signal is emitted from the common origin (at $t=t'=0$ we also assume $x=x'=0$). The light signal takes $x/c$ units of time to reach $x$ in the unprimed frame so an observer in that position, knowing he is located at $x$ can set his clock to:
$$ t(x) = \frac{x}{c} \tag{1} $$
Similarly, in the primed frame by the same method, an observer at $x'$ can set his clock to:
$$ t'(x') = \frac{x'}{c} \tag{2} $$
Now consider that after some finite* interval of time $t'$, the observers in the primed frame are interested in comparing their clocks to observers in the unprimed frame. The way they can do that, is to choose an observer located at any $x'$, and have him look at the clock of the unprimed frame that is instantaneously located at the same position as him, precisely at the same moment in which both receive the light signal and set their clocks.
Since this is a local spacetime event, both observers in the two frames that are co-located in this position receive the same light signal and set their clocks.
So, the primed observer can then compute the difference:
$$ t'(x') - \gamma t(x) \tag{3} $$
Where the factor $\gamma=\left(1-v^2/c^2\right)^{-1/2}$ is due to the observer in the primed frame accounting for the effect of time dilation (that I understand you don't have trouble with in this context), thus extending $t(x)$ by a factor $\gamma$ before subtracting. In other words, the primed observer is only interested in finding how much the clocks differ apart from the effect of time dilation.
The final piece of information we need to assume is that we know how to relate spatial coordinates between the frames, which is the first equation in your post:
$$x' = \gamma(x-vt)  \tag{4} $$
Using the above, we get:
\begin{align*} 
t' - \gamma t &= \frac{x'}{c} - \gamma\frac{x}{c} && \text{by (1) and (2)}
\\[4pt] &= \frac{\gamma(x-vt)-\gamma x}{c} && \text{by (4)}
\\[4pt] &= \require{cancel}\frac{\bcancel{\gamma x}-\gamma vt-\bcancel{\gamma x}}{c}
\\[4pt] &= \frac{-\gamma v\dfrac{x}{c}}{c} && \text{by (1)}
\\[4pt] &= \frac{-\gamma vx}{c^2}
\end{align*}
So that we finally obtain, by rearranging the terms:
$$ t' = \gamma\left(t-\frac{vx}{c^2}\right) $$

 * Note that the assumption that a finite interval of time has passed is crucial to make sense of this present derivation, and is essentially the only difficulty with the way you attempted to carry out a very similar idea. 

I don't get why $t$ is multiplied by $\gamma$ as it is the prime reference frame that we are trying to figure out shouldn't $t'$ be multiplied? Like in Feynmann's derivation of the first equation. $S'$ measures the point $x'$ and to the rest frame $S$ that distance is $x'/\gamma$, Length contractions happens to the moving frame. So by similar reasoning if we see $S'$ record a time $t'$ in the frame $S$ that time is dilated, Hence should it not be $t'\gamma - t$?

Length contracts and time dilates. Meaning that moving clocks "run slower" than clocks at rest, so that for example $1$ second in the moving frame is measured as $\gamma \times 1$ seconds in the stationary frame, with any non zero relative velocity, $\gamma > 1$. That's the opposite of what happens with lengths: $1$ meter in the moving frame is measured as $1/\gamma$ meters in the stationary frame. In my analysis, I've taken the observers in the primed frame as the stationary ones. You can also do the opposite, you'll just arrive at the inverse equation of $t$ as a function of $x'$ and $t'$

@MonsterRamen I also need to mention that the simplest reason I chose to multiply $t$ by $\gamma$ (or in other words take the primed frame as stationary) is because I wanted to find $t'$ as a function of $(t,x)$. To that end, multiplying $t'$ by some factor just complicates things. (But again, you can do that and arrive at the same result, just after a lengthier amount of algebra).
